# No longer able to Customize a Blade in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azureportal

Up until recently, it was possible to customize Azure resource blades by clicking the buttons maked "Add Tiles".

See [these out-of-date instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal-overview#how-to-customize-a-resource-blade).

It appears that the latest iteration of the portal has minor changes to the look-and-feel, but has also moved or removed vital controls.

Now there is no clickackable element titled "Add parts" or "Add tiles". The image below shows what my `Web App` blade currently looks like, and the image below that shows what it had previously looked like.

So, for THIS month at least, how do we begin customizing a blade in the Azure portal?

[image: Where did the edit button go?]

Here is what the `Web App` blade used to look like. See the 'Add tiles' buttons that are no longer there.

[image]

Comment: I disagree with the 'off-topic' close vote. Any Azure developer interacts with the Azure portal extensively.

Comment: I got a notification a while back that said something like "Looks like you have customized this blade. Blade customizations will disappear some time in the future." I think they are deprecating them, though I don't know why :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards#customizing-dashboards-versus-blades):

> Since launching dashboards a few months ago, there has been a steady decline in blade customizations and a rapid increase in dashboard customizations. This strong usage trend shows that you prefer customizing dashboards over blades. To support that trend, we will remove the ability to customize blades and dedicate our efforts to enhancing dashboard functionality.
>
> If you customized a blade, your customization will soon be removed. To preserve that customization, pin the customized tiles to a dashboard. Simply right-click the tile and select Pin to dashboard as shown in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The custom dashboards are awesome! It makes more sense to see measurements from different yet related resources on the one page.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure portal no longer allows customizing blades. This was removed due to low usage and to improve performance. Use dashboards instead.